# Docker Nodejs Instance exited "(1)"

Tags: node.js, docker

My docker nodejs instance suddenly stopped with Exited (1).
I don't know what this means, but it seems that my process stopped out of the blue.

If I look at docker logs, all it looks like is Docker stopped.

What does it mean it a Docker instance Exited with (1). Specifically for NodeJS ran docker.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried changing your nodejs entrypoint by `bash -c 'sleep infinity'` and execute nodejs entrypoint manually after `docker exec -ti <container> bash`?

Comment: exited(1) represents that it has exited with errors. when docker logs not helping, you can try `docker inspect` if that doesnt help, you can try these steps https://medium.com/@betz.mark/ten-tips-for-debugging-docker-containers-cde4da841a1d

Comment: Here you can find multiple tips to make it work the right way https://www.proximitycr.com/blog/tips-for-dockerizing-your-nodejs-app